# How to run a callback when an nvim plugin is loaded. Can I tie this back to running a callback when a plugin is required/imported?

Tags: autocmd, lua, plugin

I can see in vim how we can:

- [Call function only when the plugin is loaded](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/14907)

But I want to:

- Call function only when the plugin is `required`

Comment: I want to run one-time setup when my optional plugin (to be loaded with `packadd`) is loaded. But I cannot find the Autocmd to run after a `packadd`. Maybe there is an autocmd after a `require` was my next thought.

Comment: `require` is Lua semantics. You'd have to change its behavior somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much standard sequence of steps.

1. Install plugin under `opt` subtree
2. Execute `packadd` when required
3. Initialization works the same way as with regular plugins but right after `packadd` executed for the first time.

Comment: `Initialization works the same way as with regular plugins` - with regular plugins I will have some code in my `./plugin` folder (not my `./pack/start/*` folder(s)... this `./plugin` code will run unequivocally on startup. However, if I only wanted to run that code when I `packadd matchit` or something like that... then how do I do THAT. What is the mechanism of step 3? A plugin will have it's own ``./pack/opt/bundle/some_plugin/plugin/init.lua` folder to initialize itself. But I want to do additional work in my `./plugin/additional_config_for_some_plugin.lua` file

Comment: @AriSweedler Vim plugins normally do not require user calling any setup function for that reason. But with Neovim/Lua they do believe that "opt" is of limited use as they can "require() for everything". So if you encounter a situation where some plugin poorly fits under `/start` but still needs too many setup function call(s) then you have to admit it's a dumb piece of code and you'd better to drop it.

Comment: @AriSweedler Otherwise, you won't have anything better than wrapping both "packadd" and "plugin setup call" into a single function and/or command and use it like that. A dubious design, imo, but sometimes it gets use. See "loading on demand" section of `k-takata/minpac`, for example.

Comment: Oh interesting. So I should be using `functions that require the plugin code` instead of `opt` to delay loading a plugin. My use case is that I'm using `copilot.nvim` and I don't wanna load it until I manually load it. I'm sure I can trivially figure out what specific config delays loading of the plugin and also write a small command that lets me load it later. It's just stupid that I can't use the perfectly fine `packadd` command to do this. Maybe I'll just make a command that runs setup and THEN calls `packadd`. Exactly as u said

Comment: @AriSweedler It is much simpler always to start it but with disabled functionality.